# Can't see Reminders app option in UIActivityViewController

Tags: swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a comma-separated string like this: `"Banana,Cake"`. I want to share this string to the Reminders app through `UIActivityViewController`, but while opening the controller, I can't see an option for Reminders there.

I have seen it in the YouTube app. If a content is being shared, it shows the Reminders app as an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass an array of a string and an URL to `activityItems` in order to display Reminders as an option.

```
if let url = URL(string: "http://example.com") {
    let activityVc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: ["string", url], applicationActivities: nil)
}
```